# How to check if a Windows Identity is impersonating?

Tags: c#, windows, impersonation

Is it possible to check whether a WindowsIdentity is impersonating?

Comment: I'm not sure that would make much sense. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  Just examine the [ImpersonationLevel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonationlevel(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the `WindowsIdentity` class.

From MSDN:

> Gets the impersonation level for the user
>
> - **Anonymous** - The server process cannot obtain identification information about the client, and it cannot impersonate the client
> - **Delegation** - The server process can impersonate the client's security context on remote systems
> - **Identification** - The server process can obtain information about the client...
> - **Impersonation** - The server process can impersonate the client's security context on its local system.
> - **None**

Code snippet (modified [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
Console.WriteLine("Before impersonation: " + identity.Name);
Console.WriteLine("ImpersonationLevel: {0}", identity.ImpersonationLevel);

// Use the token handle returned by LogonUser. 
using (WindowsIdentity newId = new   
       WindowsIdentity(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle()))
{
    using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate())
    {

        // Check the identity.
        identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        Console.WriteLine("After impersonation: "+ identity.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("ImpersonationLevel: {0}", identity.ImpersonationLevel);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

### More

[Tell me more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.tokenimpersonationlevel(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I think it will do.